# Using functions with different variables

Tags: swift, function

I've had this problem for a while now, and for some reason I can't seem to find an answer. If I wanted to make an app with 10 UIlabels (using programming), I would much rather create a function so I could just say: `createLabel(size: , position: , textColor: , text: )`  My trouble is, I'm not sure how I could create a different name for each of these, so later I could refer to each of them separately if I wanted to change the text for each. Below are all the parameters I would want to have inside the function. Also, how would I create a function that would change the text of multiple labels, like `changeText(label1: , label2: , text: )`  Thanks!

```
var output = UILabel()
    output = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 100))
    output.center = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width/2, y: self.size.height * 0.08)
    output.textAlignment = .right
    output.textColor = UIColor.white
    output.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Light", size: 15.0)
    output.numberOfLines = 0;
    output.text = "12345"
    output.font = output.font.withSize(80)
    self.view?.addSubview(output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I could create a different name for each of these, so later I could refer to each of them separately if I wanted to change the text for each

To achieve this, you could save them inside a dictionary.

```
// Create data structure for labels
var labels = [String: UILabel]()

// Add label with unique name
labels["uniqueName"] = createLabel(size: , position: , textColor: , text: )

// Access label with uniqueName
let label = labels["uniqueName"]
```

> how would I create a function that would change the text of multiple labels, like changeText(label1: , label2: , text: )

You could write your function like this

```
func changeText(text: String, labels: UILabel...) {
    for label in labels {
        label.text = text
    }
}
```

Have a look at the section about variadic parameters here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the simplest way to make it, is to use tags, so you can set a tag (like 1001, 1002, 1003...) for each label and find exact label after searching it in the subviews by tag:

```
if let view = self.view?.viewWithTag(put the tag here) as? UILabel {
    //set any parameters here
}
```

Maybe there is a better way, not sure

Comment: `UIView` has a `viewWithTag` method

Comment: @vadian thanks, I've edited my answer, totally forgot about it